# Unwanted underlining on links in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, text-decorations

I am working on a [site](http://globalhealth.duke.edu) where a number of links on the home page are styled:

```
text-decoration:none;
```

This works fine in all browsers, except IE8. Please look at the home page in Firefox or Safari first then look at it in IE8 and you'll see what I mean. IE is usually more in synch thank IE7 but in this case IE7 works fine. Any clues why this is happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting detail: it only get underlined when you mouseover the container element. It "works" when the mouse is somewhere else outside the page. Thus, you're forgotten an `</a>` somewhere. [Look here at line 361 (scroll about 3/4 down)](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fglobalhealth.duke.edu%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0). Fix the other problems as well ;)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It can be somewhat problematic when you are working with other people's code. Thanks for the input.

Comment: I found the problem it was an unclosed <a> tag near the top, so the entire container was acting like a link. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the Trace Styles in the IE8 developer tools?

For instance, in the **See All Events** link, the `text-decoration` has the following inheritance.

> text-decoration - underline
>   
>     <strike>A - underline    dghi.css</strike>
>   
>     <strike>A - underline    dghi_ie8.css</strike>
>   
>     <strike>A - underline    dghi_print.css</strike>
>   
>     <strike>A.link - underline    dghi.css</strike>
>   
>     <strike>A.link - underline    dghi_ie8.css</strike>
>   
>     <strike>A.link - underline    dghi_print.css</strike>
>   
>     <strike>A.readmore - underline    dghi.css</strike>
>   
>     <strike>A.readmore - underline    dghi_ie8.css</strike>
>   
>     <strike>A.readmore - underline    dghi_print.css</strike>
>   
>     <strike>#kickers A - none    dghi.css</strike>
>   
>     <strike>#kickers A - none    dghi_ie8.css</strike>
>   
>     <strike>#kickers A - none    dghi_print.css</strike>
>   
>     <strike>#kickers A.readmore - underline    dghi.css</strike>
>   
>     <strike>#kickers A.readmore - underline    dghi_ie8.css</strike>
>   
>     #kickers A.readmore - underline    dghi_print.css

Answer (score 0):

**IE 8  underlining  issue ,**

here is how to solve the probleme you have to use the selectors `a,a:link` 
like so ;

`a,a:link,a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}`